# Sequelize ARRAY Datatype for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use the ARRAY datatype for Sequelize (Node.js SQL ORM) with PostgreSQL. However I'm not exactly sure how to utilize it. I know how to set it on the schema but how do you push new items onto the array with a write and retrieve a specific index from the array in a query, etc.

I tried going to the docs to figure this out however theres not much documentation on this as opposed to other datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

const Data = sequlize.define('data', {
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
  title: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
  imgs: { type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING) },
  wikiLink: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
  mapsLink: { type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING) },
  authorInfo: { type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING) }
});
```

honestly, i don't know, how much this is correct, but that works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).